# Django filter objects by some referencing condition

Tags: django, reference, filtering

In Django i have two models, Cateogory and Product, Product references Category in this way.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
```

I want to obtain all Category which are at least referenced by one product.

I've obtained my goal with this solution:

```
class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def has_product(self):
             products = self.product_set.all()
             if(len(products) > 0):
                   return True
             else:
                   return False

category_list = []

for cat in Category.objects.all(): 
        if cat.has_products():
             category_list.append(cat)
```

Are there any smarter solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
cats_with_prod = [c for c in Category.objects.all() if c.product_set.exists()]
```

But you can do it entirely in DB, in one query:

```
cats_with_prod = Category.objects.filter(product_set__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do it with a single list comprehension:

```
cats_with_prod = [c for c in Category.objects.all() if c.product_set.exists()]
```

Comment: Or `if c.product_set.exists()`.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Thank you, that does seem to be more efficient (re: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), will edit.